# CSS +/- x pixels for width and height animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Is there any way to animate a div (preferably without javascript) so that it gains or loses 5px in width/height? I don't mean using `scale(0.95)` or `zoom: 95%` because that depends on the original size of the div and I want to always change exactly 5px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No div sizing necessary...

http://jsfiddle.net/5rDar/4

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
    transition: padding .5s;
    padding: 10px;
}
div:hover {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Here's a variation where the primary div doesn't transition, but the parent does. This may be more useful depending on your scenario.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rDar/3

```
div.outer {
    transition: padding .5s;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
div.outer:hover {
    padding: 15px;
}
div.inner {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one did the trick, though if I were to be nitpicky I'd point out that animating small paddings like 5px doesn't result in a smooth animation at all...

Comment: It's pretty smooth for me. Maybe try shorter durations.

Comment: I see that Safari isn't terribly smooth. Firefox and IE10 are glassy.

Answer (score 2):

### Without jQuery

- Requires that the `height` increment of the `div` be known, not assumed.

```
div.growable {
    background: red;
   color: white;
   -webkit-transition: height 200ms ease-in-out;
   height: 100px;
}
div.growable:hover {
   height: 105px;
}
```

> **Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Xh4vC/

### With jQuery

- Allows the change in `height` to be an increment or decrement of an existing value, without caring what that value is.

```
$(function(){
    $('#growDiv').click(function(){
        $('div.growable-js').animate({'height' :'+=5px'}, 200);
    });
   $('#shrinkDiv').click(function(){
       $('div.growable-js').animate({'height': '-=5px'}, 200);
    });
});
```

> **Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Xh4vC/

Comment: Your no-JS solution requires pre-defined sizes, no? I'm not sure what "height increment" means.

Comment: @isherwood the CSS solution does, yes, The jQuery solution, however, doesn't care about predefined sizes : `'-=Npx'` and `'+=Npx'`

Comment: I used `height` because that's what OP wants to change. Adding padding to a `div` adds vertical real-estate, but doesn't change the height value. <-- (that can be debated)